# Facebook Download photo and ServerXMLHTTP

Tags: facebook, asp-classic, serverxmlhttp

Hello and thanks in advance. Before to post here i search a lot in the net and here as well.

I have a site that let the user join with their facebook profile so with their permission (FB application) the web will download their main photo.

I used this script server side with classic ASP (and i must use ASP) to download the main photo and in random cases it through an error: `msxml3.dll The parameter is incorrect.`

```vb
''DownloadURL is the url pf the photo 
''example "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.....xxxxxx.jpg"

Dim objXML
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXML.Open "GET", DownloadURL , true  ' <-- this line get the error sometimes

objXML.Send
'.... code to handle the request
' and save photo using ADODB.Stream
```

But if i try on my workstation **the same photo url** to reproduce the error, damn this work fine so i cant check what is the problem.

I use Windows 2008 server SE SP2 and IIS7

my questions are:

1. Is MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP obsolete ?
2. what more do i need to know ?
3. is this related to the client browser (example IE) ?
4. Any suggestions or tips that i can receive from the gurus here ?

Thanks in advance for this help

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would suggest that is likely causing a lot of your problems is to not use the profile.ak.fbcdn.net url. That url is not necessarily constant. I would suggest using the supported url of http://graph.facebook.com/facebookid/photo where facebookid is the id of the user who's photo you are downloading.

Regarding the use of MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP I haven't used that stuff in ages, but it seems like that object probably isn't the best for downloading an image file. Check out this discussion that may be relevant: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread153966.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but about the URL Photo i used an FB application that are using the FQL query to get the exact url of the photo associated to the user and in my example above was just an example.